# Display sum of column from table

Tags: php, mysql

Hey there I have a table (named vanzari) with a column named totaldeplata
i want to display the sum of all numbers from column nammed totaldeplata from current date, there is a column nammed datainregistrarii where is registered the date by this

format `Dec 7, 2017 - 12:51`

this is the code, i don't get any errors but it does not display the sum

```
<?php    
$query = "SELECT * FROM vanzari WHERE datainregistrarii >= CURRENT_DATE()";
 $query_run = mysql_query($query);

 $qty= 0;
 while ($num = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query_run)) {
  $qty += $num['totaldeplata'];
 }
 echo $qty;

  ?>
```

Any idea why it doesn't display the sum of column from the current day?

Comment: SELECT SUM(COLOUMN) FROM vanzari WHERE datainregistrarii >= CURRENT_DATE()

Comment: Try this :- `SELECT SUM(totaldeplata) FROM vanzari WHERE datainregistrarii >= CURRENT_DATE()`

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated and removed library now. Quickly upgrade to PHP7 along with `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: It won't work because date format of `datainregistrarii`and `CUURENT_DATE()` is different.

Comment: what format of date in datainregistrarii

Comment: and what should i do?

Comment: <?php echo date("M j, Y - g:i"); ?> this is the date formmat

Comment: Dec 7, 2017 - 12:51   <- this is the date format that it displays

Comment: Perhaps people cannot register in the future.

Comment: Strawberry what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There 2 possibilities :

1. Using Query you can get total.
   SELECT SUM(totaldeplata) FROM vanzari WHERE datainregistrarii >= CURRENT_DATE()
2. You can Type Cast the variable. ie: (int)$num['totaldeplata'];

   $query = "SELECT * FROM vanzari WHERE datainregistrarii >= CURRENT_DATE()";
        $query_run = mysql_query($query);

   ```
    $qty= 0;
    while ($num = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query_run)) {
      $qty += (int)$num['totaldeplata'];
    }
    echo $qty;

   ?>
   ```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I really apreciate your answear, none of them are not working.
This is what i got.

```
<?php    
 (int)$num['totaldeplata'];

 $query = "SELECT * FROM vanzari WHERE datainregistrarii >= CURRENT_DATE()"; 

 $query_run = mysql_query($query);
 $qty= 0;
 while ($num = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query_run)) {
  $qty += (int)$num['totaldeplata'];
 }
 echo $qty;

 ?>
```